# React Native - VirtualizedList: You have a large list that is slow to update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

### Introduction

I am having serious performance issues with my VirtualizedList (infinite scroll)... I have been following [this](https://reactnative.dev/docs/optimizing-flatlist-configuration) to improve it but still working really slow.

When I scroll down, the UI threads go from 60fps to 30fps, and the JS thread from 60fps to 10/20fps (sometimes to 0fps). On iOS (iPhone 6) it seems to go smoothy than on my Android (Samsung Galaxy S8+)

My VirtualizedList is rendering items with different heights, and it fetches the data when its end is reached. My item extends from React.PureComponent, as it is recommended:

> VirtualizedList: You have a large list that is slow to update - make sure your renderItem function renders components that follow React performance best practices like PureComponent, shouldComponentUpdate, etc. Object {
> "contentLength": 20720,
> "dt": 532,
> "prevDt": 2933,
> }

This issue comes when I scroll down around 20 items...

### Code

Here is the code of the VirtualizedList:

```
const keyExtractor = ({ id }) => id;
...
 
getItem = (data, index) => data[index];

getItemCount = (data) => data.length;

renderItem = ({ item, index }) => {
 const {
   images,
   dimensions,
   description,
   location,
   likes,
   comments,
   date,
 } = item;

 return (
   <Card
     images={images}
     postDimensions={dimensions}
     description={description}
     location={location}
     likes={likes}
     comments={comments}
     date={date}
   />
 );
};

<VirtualizedList
    data={data}
    getItem={this.getItem}
    getItemCount={this.getItemCount}
    keyExtractor={keyExtractor}
    listKey={listKey}
    legacyImplementation={false}
    numColumns={1}
    renderItem={this.renderItem}
    initialNumToRender={MAX_POSTS_TO_RETRIEVE_LENGTH} // 10
    windowSize={32}
    maxToRenderPerBatch={15}
    updateCellsBatchingPeriod={50}
    removeClippedSubviews={false}
    ListFooterComponent={this.renderFooter}
    ListEmptyComponent={ListEmptyComponent}
    onEndReached={onEndReached}
    onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
/>
```

Pd: each item I am rendering has an unique id.

### What I have tried

I have tried to implement my own getItemLayout method for the List but for some reason it doesn't work properly.

> Warning: Failed frame type: The frame `frame.length` is marked as required in `VirtualizedList.getItemLayout`, but its value is `undefined`.

```
itemHeights = [];

getItemLayout = (data, index) => {
  const length = this.itemHeights[index];
  const offset = this.itemHeights.slice(0,index).reduce((a, c) => a + c, 0)
  return {length, offset, index}
}

renderItem = ({ item, index }) => {
 const {
   images,
   dimensions,
   description,
   location,
   likes,
   comments,
   date,
 } = item;

 return (
   <View onLayout={(event) => this.itemHeights[index] = event.nativeEvent.layout.height}>
    <Card
      images={images}
      postDimensions={dimensions}
      description={description}
      location={location}
      likes={likes}
      comments={comments}
      date={date}
    />
   </View>
 );
};

<VirtualizedList
    data={data}
    getItem={this.getItem}
    getItemCount={this.getItemCount}
    getItemLayout={this.getItemLayout}
    keyExtractor={keyExtractor}
    listKey={listKey}
    legacyImplementation={false}
    numColumns={1}
    renderItem={this.renderItem}
    initialNumToRender={MAX_POSTS_TO_RETRIEVE_LENGTH} // 10
    windowSize={32}
    maxToRenderPerBatch={15}
    updateCellsBatchingPeriod={50}
    removeClippedSubviews={false}
    ListFooterComponent={this.renderFooter}
    ListEmptyComponent={ListEmptyComponent}
    onEndReached={onEndReached}
    onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
/>
```

Any ideas? I have seen that it is a common problem but I haven't found any solution.

### UPDATE

To solve the issue I was getting with getItemLayout just do:

```
getItemLayout = (data, index) => {
  const length = this.itemHeights[index] || 0; // <----- if undefined return 0
  const offset = this.itemHeights.slice(0,index).reduce((a, c) => a + c, 0)
  return {length, offset, index}
}
```

Comment: Try to comment the images and see if that is cause of the slow rendering. It will not your problem but you will know what the source of the problem is.

Comment: What do you mean by comment the images? Replacing/commenting the Card component with an other??

Comment: Not the whole Card component but only the <Image>'s tag. This way you will have the list without images. If the performance improves you'll know its the images causing the problem

Comment: Yes, it seems that the problem is with the images... When I removed this tag, the UI thread minmum value was 50fps when scrolling, and the JS thread 50fps too. I have also  appreciated that the image causes the item to be removed when it goes ouside the viewport... Maybe this is because I am getting the images from my device cache (I cached them when they are rendered)...

Comment: Okey, the problem isn't with the cached image. I have implemented my own component to render images from cache progresivelly and performance is better than using the default Image component from react native. @D10S do you know if the problem can be with the image quality?

Comment: I don't know why but react-native has those images issues. Try using [this library](https://github.com/DylanVann/react-native-fast-image#---fastimage), I never used it by myself so will appreciate if you let me know if and how did it help (fps wise).

Comment: Okey, I will try it tonight and comment.

Comment: At last I haven't been able to use this library as it is not compatible with my technlogy stack :C but reducing the number of nested views and the image quality (from 1080p to 720p) in combination with my custom progressive cached image component has improved the FlatList performance drastically..

Comment: I'm Glad for you. Thank you for updating.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If this happen to someone, just use my custom getItemLayout function and follow these [steps](https://codingislove.com/optimize-react-native-flatlist-performance/)

Using those values has worked for me.

```
    initialNumToRender={10}
    windowSize={5}
    maxToRenderPerBatch={5}
    updateCellsBatchingPeriod={30}
    removeClippedSubviews={false}
    ...
    onEndReachedThreshold={0.1}
```

Pd: my viewport is covered with 1.5 items